# What Is Done When Spring Form Tags Are Limited

Tags: html, spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

What happens when using **SpringMVC** and the **Spring Tag library** does not have the tags you require? What can the developer use that will allow automated **databinding**, does the developer now have to use the old way of doing **databinding** which involves using the **http** **request**, **response** to get and set form elements?

Can the developer add to the **Spring-Form tags**? I am confused on how to approach this since i am using tags form **html5** and they do not exist in the **Spring Tag library.**

Can someone advise me on the best approach to handling a problem such as this. I have been asking questions on how does one use a `**<canvas>**` tag in **SpringMVC** so that it allows automated **databinding** like spring `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still get the binding done by providing the `name` attribute value of canvas tag same as the name of the field in your pojo you want to bind the value with.

Eg. if your field name in pojo is myCanvas, then you can give the same name in `name` attribute of canvas tag. So that the binding gets done.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: are you serious does that work i am going to try and see if name attribute is valid for this element

Comment: i am getting an undefined attribute name for tag

Comment: oh sorry for that. I thought there must be a name attribute as per this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_canvas.htm

And I thought its a standard attribute so it must be there. But I am sure that if name attribute is there then it can be used to bind. :)

Comment: this tag doesnt have a name attribute, any ideas ?

Comment: you can give it a try. I am not sure. :)